# Google App Engine is not servig my defined entrypoint in app.yaml

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, gunicorn

Google App Engine will not serve my defined entrypoint on python37 runtime. GAE still try to serve a `main.py` file.

**Project structure**

```
/backend/__init__.py
/backend/views.py
/backend/models.py
app.yaml
```

**app.yaml**

```
service: backend
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT backend:app
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

**/backend/**init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask
...
app = Flask(__name__)
...
import backend.models
import backend.views
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**GAE error message**

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

Comment: Sometimes it happens when gunicorn was not installed, can you share also your requirement.txt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify a custom `entrypoint` in your `app.yaml` file with `gunicorn` you have to install `gunicorn` in your `requirements.txt`. That did the trick for me and solved this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure gunicorn to look at the directory where your `init.py` is located. There are two ways to do this on your entrypoint:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT --chdir backend init:app
```

or

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT backend.init:app
```